# 2 problems after installing Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I am having 2 problems after installing Ubuntu 17.04. The first is slow connection. I cannot open any website. I get cannot reach service. I cannot even update through `apt-get update`.

The second error I get when I boot to Windows 7 then boot to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu through USB flash memory. Booted to Windows 7 then booted to Ubuntu again, I found this message without missing with any configuration. I still get this error even if I reinstalled Ubuntu then booted to Windows 7 then booted to Ubuntu again

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you say Yes to run fsck ?

Comment: Did not say anything. I just found this after booting from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. I still get this message even after reinstalling Ubuntu

Comment: "The first which probably everyone has is slow connection"  Care to elaborate?  If everyone has it then it's not slow, it's the normal speed.

Comment: From line 6 to line 12 in your screendump, there are errors / information about fsck ... and presumably you have answered something to `... Run fsck? ` in line 12.

Comment: @DrEval I cannot open any website. I get cannot reach service. I cannot even update through apt-get update